# Compression dictionary with very fast int->data lookups, and fast reverse lookups (search/insert/delete data)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, dictionary

I would like to implement a dictionary that pairs unique heterogeneous data (variant) with unique `int` so that instead of repeating the value (that may be large) I would repeat the `int`.  When needed, I would convert it via the dictionary to the original value.

The dataset will be large, so (int->data) in `O(1)` is important. (data->int) and insert/delete should all be `O(log n)` average case, since these operations are less important.  Order of the data is of no concern, but insert/delete must not invalidate existing int keys.

I have tried **hash-table** and **SSTable** approaches.  With hash-table the required storage is rather high even when using the hashed value as indice, not storing it with the values. Collissions lowers the efficiency but the amortized complexity is `O(1)` for all of the operations. SSTable on the other hand offers worse complexities for manipulation and duplicates the values (once for vector storage, once for the map-index). The overall memory consumption is only slightly lower than that of hash-table dictionary.

Requirements in summary of Dictionary:

- Lookup int->data: O(1)
- Lookup data->int: O(log n) at worst
- Insertion: O(log n) at worst
- Removal: O(log n) at worst [or alternative means like garbage collection that could perform worse if not being run all the time]
- *Minimum memory requirements possible*

Is there a way to improve upon the design of a dictionary to further reduce the memory requirements while retaining `O(1)` int->data lookup and reasonable insertion/removal/data->int?

Comment: People spend years optimizing the library functions like the one you are talking about. If there is a way to improve it, it is likely beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: So the int->data map needs to support removal of an arbitrary entry?  And you also need better than O(n) search for an existing data item?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, pretty much. Although arguably removal of the entries might not be needed if I let the dictionary only to grow and if some entries become unused later they will still be there and might yet become used later. Or I could create some kind of clean-up or garbage collection for it. Not really all that relevant to the quesstion though imho.

Comment: @Resurrection: It's very relevant.  Keeping the entries in a `std::vector` instead of linked-list or tree makes the `int`->data extremely cheap, because it's just a pointer offset from the start of the vector.  It also means extremely low overhead for adding new ones: just `push_back`.  Destroying is also very cheap: one big deallocation instead of freeing many nodes.  You could still support removal with a free-list or something, I guess.  Check the head of the free list, otherwise push_back.

Comment: You'd need some kind of reverse index, too, to make the data->`int` searches fast.  Maybe a BST, where each node has an `int` index into the `vector`?  Yeah, this will work.  Turning it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `int`->data speed is the most important thing, you should set things up so that's just an array-indexing operation.

Keep your data objects in a `std::vector<data> forward_map`.  int->data is just a `forward_map[i]` lookup, which is O(1) with constant factors that are about as low as possible.

---

#### Use a *separate* data structure to support the search/insert/delete operations.

Depending on what comparison operations your "data" objects support, maybe a binary search tree or a [std::unordered set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) would be good choices.  The "value" type of the BST / set is just an `int`, but comparisons on those `int`s actually compare `forward_map[i] < forward_map[j]`, *not* according to `i < j`.

So lets say you have a `std::unordered_set< forward_map_reference_t > reverse_map`.  (It's not actually this easy with STL containers, see below.)

We're actually using a set as a map:  **The key is `forward_map[val]`, and the value is `int val` itself.**

To find the reverse_map entry for a given `int k`, you need to actually search it for `forward_map[k]`.

- `const data_t & lookup(int k) { return forward_map[k]; }`
- **`int search(const data_t &)`**: `reverse_map.find()` is efficient.
- **`delete(const data_t &)`**: search & delete the reverse_map entry, returning `int k`.  Add `k` to a LIFO free-list for the forward_map.  (Don't touch the forward_map entry.  If you need to detect use-after-free of forward_map entries, then zero it at this point or something.)
- **`insert(const data_t &)`**: check the head of the free-list for an entry to reuse, otherwise `forward_map.push_back()`.  `k` = the position you put the entry in the forward map.  Add that `k` to the reverse map.

To avoid storing another copy of the `data_t` items, reverse_map needs to refer to the forward_map inside its search operations.

There's a potentially-large advantage to using a reverse_map based on a hash-table, rather than a search tree, because of cache-misses.  Normally all the data needed to compare a key with a tree node is present in the node, but in this case it's a reference to forward_map.  Not only can loads from reverse_map itself cache-miss, so can forward_map[k].  (Loads from unknown addresses can't get started early, unlike the known-address case on out-of-order CPUs, so this is extra bad).  Speculative execution may get the next load from reverse_map started, but things are still bad.    **A hash table requires significantly fewer total key comparisons**, which is a big plus.

---

#### Using STL containers?

There's actually a **chicken and egg problem** for using STL containers here:  Consider a `std::unordered_set<int>`:  The Key type is `int`.  We'd use a custom `KeyEqual` function that compares based on `forward_map[i]`.  But there's only `.find(const Key& key)`, not `.find(const data_t&)`.

An ugly workaround would be to temporarily copy a `data_t` into a free slot in `forward_map` so it would have an index that we could pass to `unordered_set<int, custom_compare>::find`, but this extra copying is dumb.

Another **bad option (that probably won't optimize away at compile time)** would be a class with a virtual function to access a `data_t`.  The map holds a class with a single `int` member.  We'd pass `.find()` a derived class that also has a `data_t &`, and refers to that instead of the int array index in its overload of the virtual function that's used by the Hash and KeyEquals functions.

You might have to build your own custom data structure, or use something other than STL, unless there's a way to get STL to accept keys of a different type from the existing set members.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks a lot. I had it done similarly already but I had that copy of the data in the reverse_map which I felt was unnecessary but could not figure out how to get rid off it. Until now. :-)

Comment: @Resurrection: Can you see a way to use STL unordered_set or something for the reverse_map?  Or are you just going to implement it yourself?

Comment: Using unordered_set: it allows to use custom "equal to" template argument that could be used to supply custom one that would compare values from forward_map instead of the indices. I have my own implementation of red black tree so I will try that as well. Plus I use Qt primarily so I will try those containers as well however they are pretty expensive memory-wise. I have also custom hash-table set implemented using qHash that uses minimum amount of memory I could manage so I will consider that as well.

Comment: @Resurrection: I saw the `KeyEqual` template parameter, but there's a chicken-and-egg problem here:  search/ins/del don't have an `int` yet, so they need to compare a `data_t` search key against `int` keys in the set.  This is why I was talking about virtual function overloads as a way to keep the value-type of the set holding just a single `int`...

Comment: Ok this might be a stretch but one could probably "abuse" the `Allocator`. So if the map is declared of `Key` that is `data_t` it would, through custom `Allocator`, create only `int`. Then it should work with similar `Hash` and `Pred` parameters. But that sounds quite unorthodox tbh. Besides the hash table might not be viable after all because since `data_t` is a variant type (`QVariant` actually) it might be better to use search tree because more types support `operator<` than value hashing. Worse time complexity though.

Comment: @Resurrection: if you have a hash function that works on a `data_t`, you can in theory use a hash table holding `int` values as a reverse map.  I haven't worked with custom Allocators, so IDK if that would work.  A hash table is going to allocate a big buffer of many values, and use its own assumptions about how wide each element is.  You don't just have to do a narrower allocation, you have to get the array indexing to know about it.  (BTW, I just updated my answer with a rewrite to present the good part better, and the chicken-and-egg problem for STL containers at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intrusive linked list.  For example:

```
struct Node {
    Node *prev, *next;
    variant<int, float, vector<string>> data;
};
```

Now, instead of storing an `int` to locate one of these things, just store a `Node*`.  When you want to delete one:

```
~Node() {
    if (prev) prev->next = next;
    if (next) next->prev = prev;
}
```

Now it will disappear itself from the list when you call `delete node`.

Predictably, Boost has an implementation with lots of fancy features: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/intrusive.html

Comment: `variant` ? Is that boost or standard C++ ? I tried to google it and I can't find it as a C++

Comment: I think the OP also needs to search the container with a `data` item as the key, to find the `int` (or `Node*`).  O(N) time for that might be unacceptable.  The question isn't really clear enough, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes What exactly is not clear? I specified explicitly I need log n lookup of data->int...

Comment: @Resurrection: you said "might be".  If that's an upper-bound on acceptable time complexity, you need to edit the question.  You could improve the question anyway by laying out your requirements in bullet points, instead of scattered through the text.